# Rails engines tutorial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I am following this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html
about rails engines and maybe I did something wrong.
Getting following error in the browser.

Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Blorgh::ApplicationController

Extracted source (around line #492):

```
 if loading.include?(expanded)
      raise "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant #{qualified_name}"
    else
      require_or_load(expanded, qualified_name)
      raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a mistake in your code, but all the code you posted looks right. Post relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app/controllers/blorgh/application_controller.rb, make sure you have

```
class Blorgh::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
```

not

```
module Blorgh
  class ApplicationController < ApplicationController
```

The second option will scope the inherited ApplicationController to the Blorgh module as well - hence the circularity